# What does desktop_Comment_boilerplate mean?

Tags: application-development

I'm uploading a click package and it's being sent back with the following message:

```
desktop_Comment_boilerplate
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Ubuntu SDK provides the comment “My project description” in the .desktop file. Please provide a better description of your app, so users know what they’re looking at.