# ubuntu sdk ,run default app on ubuntu phone

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-touch, application-development, sdk

I'm trying  to run a default qml application on my phone. But it's not working :/

developer mode is enabled.

the first error includes this link:
[error1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/417359/what-does-desktop-comment-boilerplate-mean/417360)
Where have I to enter this description?

**Second error:**

> :-1: Warnung: desktop:Exec:untitled4: found unexpected Exec with 
>   architecture 'all': ./qtc_device_debughelper.py

-> What does this mean? What should I do ?

**Third Error**

> :-1: Warnung: security:policy_groups_safe:untitled4:debug: (REJECT) reserved policy group 'debug': not for production use
>   The debug policy group is automatically injected and should only be used for development.
>   Please use the publish mode to create a package for the store!

-> What does it mean and what have i to do ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved changing the Comment in the desktop file. For further Information just add a comment

Comment: If you have further information you should [edit] it into your answer so as to remove it from the low quality answer queue. Thank you!